# Error Parsing WSDL - Worklight 6.1 - Backend Discovery Service

Tags: soap, wsdl, ibm-mobilefirst, service-discovery, worklight-waf

Testing the new backend discovery feature in WL6.1 used for a web service (SOAP) connection, we found a wrong import procedures from WSDL parsing. In particular, for each procedure offered by the SOAP server and exposed in the related WSDL the backend discovery service found only one input/output parameter although the procedures are composed of more than one input parameter. The problem seems to be a misinterpretation of the WSDL associated with the SOAP server.

thanks,

Here the WSDL:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/15425546/Ws_StoreSurfer.xml

Comment: Is this WSDL accessible? It can be helpful as a test case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is seems that WL v6.1 indeed has a problem with muli-parts and showing only one part of the input/output of a procedure.
Tested it with a new version of WL (not yet released) and it seems like the problem has already been addressed (see below). You will therefore get it solved in the next update of your Worklight Studio.

If you are an IBM business partner or customer you can open a PMR and request an intermittent iFix.

[image]